# What is the standard way of transitioning between views?

Tags: wpf, transition, animation

I was wondering if there is a standard way (or best-practices way) of transitioning between two views in WPF?

For example, if you are looking at one particular view, and you click a button (e.g. a "Next" button) and you want to transition into the next view, what is the best-practices way of doing that?

I have seen a few examples online, but they are all different in how they handle it.

Also, these are animated transitions I would like to be able to do (i.e. slide, fade, etc.).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pavan Podila has some very good transition examples: [TransitionContainer: Easy transitions between views](http://blog.pixelingene.com/?p=12). This is a part of his [FluidKit](http://www.codeplex.com/fluidkit) library.

But best practices vary from project to project. It may be as simple as having a [Frame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx) control with set of pages. Or as complex as one can imagine.

Cheers, Anvaka.

Comment: Thank you Anvaka, I will have a look at that.